# navigation drawer with redux using react navigation

Tags: react-native, redux, navigation-drawer

How can I integrate redux with navigation drawer using react navigation in react native. here is my code without redux

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { AppRegistry } from "react-native";
import { StackNavigator, DrawerNavigator } from "react-navigation";
import DrawerMenu from "./containers/DrawerMenu";
import BarChart from "./containers/BarChart";
import PieChart from "./containers/PieChart";
import LineChart from "./containers/LineChart";

const MainScreenNavigator = StackNavigator ({
    bChart: { screen: BarChart },
    pChart: { screen: PieChart },
    lChart: { screen: LineChart }
});
const Drawer = DrawerNavigator (
    {
        Main: { screen: MainScreenNavigator }
    },
    {
        contentComponent: DrawerMenu,
        drawerWidth: 200
    }
);
export default Drawer;
```

Comment: Have you already integrated redux with your application?

Comment: You should have a look at the official guide [React Navigation - Redux integration](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/redux-integration.html).

Answer (score 0):

Its not suggested to connect React Navigation with Redux ([redux-integration](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/redux-integration.html)). Personally, I never had any problems when they are seperated even when I use several nested navigators. You don't have to keep the navigator in the store. You should consider seperating them.